# "... who am I?" or "... who is me?"?

Tags: grammar, questions, subordinate-clauses

I have a question, but I don't know how to ask it correctly.
Can you help me to choose and explain it please?

I want to ask the next question:

```
If Kate and John are students, then who [(am I) or (is me)]?
```

I think, that "am I" is correctly, but not sure.

Comment: I don't understand the connection between the two halves of the sentence ... can you provide a bit more context/explain the situation where somebody would say a sentence like this? Why is it relevant that Kate and John are students?

Comment: Okay, Kate and John told that they were students. So, if they are students, I can't be a student (I don't want to be because of them) and I want to ask them and others who (or what) can I be. Also I want that all know that they are students, when I ask who (or what) can I be.

Comment: I see. In that case, you're correct that "who am I" would be preferable. "Who is me" is a very unlikely question. A side point: in an *indirect* question that is embedded in a surrounding clause, like the one in your previous comment ("I want to ask them ... who can I be"), it's actually better not to use inversion: "I want to **ask them who I can be**" uses a  more standard word order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use "who am I". The subject is "I"; the word "who" is not the subject, but comes at the start because it is a *wh*-word. The verb (or auxiliary) "am" comes before the subject because this is a question with subject-verb (subject-auxiliary) inversion, but it still agrees with the subject "I".